# Recursive output of self static contained subclass of string in gdb print command

Tags: c++, class, static, gdb, self-contained

everyone,

I am using OpenFOAM and it made its own Foam::string and Foam::word type like this:

```
(gdb) ptype Foam::word
type = class Foam::word : public Foam::string {
  public:
    static pointer typeName;
    static int debug;
    static const Foam::word null;

  private:
    void stripInvalid(void);
  public:
    word(void);
    word(const Foam::word &);
    word(pointer, bool);
    word(pointer, size_type, bool);
    word(const Foam::string &, bool);
    word(const std::__cxx11::string &, bool);
    word(Foam::Istream &);
    static bool valid(char);
    void operator=(const Foam::word &);
    void operator=(const Foam::string &);
    void operator=(const std::__cxx11::string &);
    void operator=(pointer);
}
(gdb) ptype Foam::string
type = class Foam::string : public std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > {
  public:
    static pointer typeName;
    static int debug;
    static const Foam::string null;

    string(void);
    string(const std::__cxx11::string &);
    string(pointer);
    string(pointer, size_type);
    string(char);
    string(Foam::Istream &);
    size_type count(char) const;
    bool match(const std::__cxx11::string &) const;
    Foam::string & replace(const Foam::string &, const Foam::string &, size_type);
    Foam::string & replaceAll(const Foam::string &, const Foam::string &, size_type);
    Foam::string & expand(bool);
    bool removeRepeated(char);
    Foam::string removeRepeated(char) const;
    bool removeTrailing(char);
    Foam::string removeTrailing(char) const;
    Foam::string operator()(size_type, size_type) const;
    Foam::string operator()(size_type) const;
    static bool stripInvalid<Foam::word>(Foam::string &);
    static bool stripInvalid<Foam::fileName>(Foam::string &);
    static bool valid<Foam::word>(const Foam::string &);
    static bool valid<Foam::fileName>(const Foam::string &);
}
```

Now, it is possible to print `Foam::string::null` like this:

```
(gdb) p Foam::string::null
$82 = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "",
    static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}}
```

However, when it comes to `Foam::word::null`, gdb will produce infinite recursive output like this:

```
(gdb) p Foam::word::null
$83 = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
    static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
  static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
      static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
    static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
        static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
      static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
          static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
        static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
            static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
          static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
              static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
            static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
                static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
              static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
                  static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
                static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
                    static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
                  static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
                      static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
                    static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
                        static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
                      static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
                          static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
                        static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
                            static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
                          static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
                              static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
                            static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0,
                                static null = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string", static debug = 0, static null = <same as static member of an already seen type>}},
                              static typeName = 0x7ffff4e398eb "word", static debug = 0, static null = {<Foam::string> = {<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >> = "", static typeName = 0x7ffff4e38b8a "string",
```

My question is:

What is wrong with this kind of c++ class structure in gdb and how to print a better result.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `std::__cxx11::basic_string` instead of regular `std::string`?

Answer (score 7):

You could try this:

```
set print static-members off
```

This should result in a more manageable output because the recursion happens through a static member.  Alternatively, you could write a [Python pretty-printer](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html) for the type, but that is of course much more involved.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue with eclipse, resulting in a silent crash of the debugging session.
This really blows, and 'set print static-members off' is a workaround, but not a viable solution

Comment: The issue is supposedly fixed with GDB 8.1 (not verified it myself), see the corresponding commit:

https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=a43f3893f6cb66dfca7f628cd159a008009ad06f